# Cloud Firestore - Dynamic Querying

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `Collection` in Cloud Firestore that has a certain number of items, let's call it `Collection` "X". This number of items will constantly be changing. At any given time, I want to listen for the number of items in this `Collection` and create several `whereEqualto()` calls on a `Query` object that is based on another 'Collection', let's call it "Y":

```
Query queryStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("Y")
            .whereEqualTo(USER_ID_LABEL,  "item 1 from X")
            .whereEqualTo(USER_ID_LABEL,  "item 2 from X")
            .whereEqualTo(USER_ID_LABEL,  "item 3 from X");
            //Could be more than 3, could be less than 3, constantly changing
```

Essentially, the number of `whereEqualTo()` will be dynamic.

Is this type of query possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  [whereEqualTo()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#whereEqualTo(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) returns a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query) object, which can be used to build up the final query you need. There's no obligation to chain the methods all at once, as you've demonstrated in your question. What you've written is equivalent to this:

```
Query queryStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Y")
queryStore = queryStore.whereEqualTo(USER_ID_LABEL,  "item 1 from X");
queryStore = queryStore.whereEqualTo(USER_ID_LABEL,  "item 2 from X");
queryStore = queryStore.whereEqualTo(USER_ID_LABEL,  "item 3 from X");
```

Comment: Got it, so when I pass `queryStore` into my `FirebaseRecyclerOptions`, it will consider all `where` conditions and not just the last? In other words it is cumulative?

Comment: Thanks - is there also a way to clear/reset the Query?

Comment: No, a Query is an immutable object.  Read the javadoc again carefully (highlighting mine): "Creates and returns a **new** Query with the **additional filter**..".  If you want to start over, create a new Query from the point where you want to start building.

Comment: I have actually updated my code. For whatever reason I cannot understand, the `RecyclerView` is not populating the data as "Following" is changed. I am unsure why.....

Comment: You completely rewrote your question, which has invalidated the answer I gave to the first question.  If you have a followup question, you should ask a new question, not rewrite your first question.

Comment: Noted - I have reverted back