# How to create firestore dynamic queries correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am trying to build a dynamic query for firestore using this approach: [Cloud Firestore - Dynamic Querying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50184958/cloud-firestore-dynamic-querying)

Here is how I build my query:

```
buildQueryRef(ref: firebase.firestore.CollectionReference, queryMap: ProductQueryMap, lastDoc?: Item) {

    var query : Query = ref; 
    
    if (queryMap.minPrice)
      query = query.where("price", ">=", queryMap.minPrice) || ref.where("price", ">=", queryMap.minPrice);

    if (queryMap.maxPrice)
      query = query.where("price", "<=", queryMap.maxPrice) || ref.where("price", "<=", queryMap.maxPrice);

    if (queryMap.type)
      query = query.where("type", "==", queryMap.type) || ref.where("type", "==", queryMap.type);

    if (queryMap.orType)
      query = query.where("type", "in", queryMap.type) || ref.where("type", "in", queryMap.type);

    if (queryMap.status)
      query = query.where("status", "in", queryMap.status) || ref.where("status", "in", queryMap.status);

    if (queryMap.keywords || queryMap.orKeywords)
      query = query.where("keywords", "array-contains-any", queryMap.keywords) || ref.where("keywords", "array-contains-any", queryMap.keywords);

    if (queryMap.userId) {
      query = query.where("userId", "==", queryMap.userId) || ref.where("userId", "==", queryMap.userId);
      // query.orderBy("userId", "desc");
      // orderArr.push("userId");
    }
    if (queryMap.minPrice || queryMap.maxPrice)
      query = query.orderBy("price", "asc") || ref.orderBy("price", "asc");

    query = query.orderBy("created", "desc") || ref.orderBy("created", "desc");

    if (lastDoc)

      query = query.startAfter(lastDoc.created) || ref.startAfter(lastDoc.created);

    query = query.limit(12) || ref.limit(12);
    return query;
  }
```

So, for example, if I make a query that has no parameters, it will only set the orderBy("created", "desc") and limit(12) and will work just fine, but as soon as it receives any other parameters like userId or type it returns no documents.

At first there was an error message with a link to create a composite index in firestore, but then I created the indexes as suggested and then it didn't return any documents.

I want to know if it is possible to make queries with this approach, because it would not be practical to write a query for every possible combination of parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not needed: `query = query.where("price", ">=", queryMap.minPrice) || ref.where("price", ">=", queryMap.minPrice);`. Instead you can just do `query = query.where("price", ">=", queryMap.minPrice);`.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore requires that indexes must be present before making a query successfully.  How you create them is up to you, but it's not an optional step.  If you have a lot of combinations of ordering and filters to apply, you will either have to create them all manually as you have been, or find some way to automate that.

You might find it helpful to [generate a JSON description](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/firestore/indexes) of indexes to [deploy with the Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#use_the_firebase_cli), or [invoke the REST API directly](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#v1projectsdatabasescollectiongroupsindexes).  Either way, it is not trivial work.

Comment: Hello @Doug Stevenson. As you mention, I have created a pair of indexes, one for querying items for a userId and one for type, since firestore demanded such indexes. The issue is that none of them appear to work. For example, when I make the query like this: `this.fs.collection("products", ref => ref.where("userId", "==", userId).orderBy("created", "desc").startAfter(lastDoc.created).limit(12)).valueChanges().subscribe(resolve, reject);` works fine, but built the other way wont

Comment: If your query is returning no documents, that's not a problem with indexes.  That's just a result of no matching documents.  A lack of appropriate index will always cause an error.  Firestore will not execute a query without one.

Comment: If there where no matching documents the "static" query would return 0 documents as well, that is what I don't understand, but I guess I will have to figure out another solution. Thanks anyway.